# Remove parent of window or form

Tags: process, window, pinvoke, parent-child

How can I make a process whose parent has been set to a control of my application "pop-out" of my application and become a top-level window?

I've tried using `SetParent(WindowHandle, null);` but IntPtr it says that it is a non-nullable type.

Comment: The question makes no sense, you don't have a separate "managed process" in your application.  There's just one.

Comment: @HansPassant I have attempted to correct my use of terminology.

Comment: @HansPassant "managed" was not the correct word... My application uses a WindowsFormsHost as a parent for a process that it has started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to modify the parent of a window. The function you need is [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541.aspx). Your p/invoke looks like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

From the documentation:

> **hWndNewParent**
>
> A handle to the new parent window. If this parameter is NULL, the
>   desktop window becomes the new parent window.

So, you simply pass `NULL` as `hWndNewParent`. In C# terms, that is done like this:

```
SetParent(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero);
```

However, there is more. In the remarks you will find this text:

> For compatibility reasons, SetParent does not modify the WS_CHILD or
>   WS_POPUP window styles of the window whose parent is being changed.
>   Therefore, if hWndNewParent is NULL, you should also clear the
>   WS_CHILD bit and set the WS_POPUP style after calling SetParent.
>   Conversely, if hWndNewParent is not NULL and the window was previously
>   a child of the desktop, you should clear the WS_POPUP style and set
>   the WS_CHILD style before calling SetParent.

So, in your case you do need to modify the window style for the window. You need to clear `WS_CHILD`, and set `WS_POPUP`.

```
uint style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style = (style | WS_POPUP) & (~WS_CHILD);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what the parent of any top-level window is using the following:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);
```

The result is '0'.

Thus you can make your process become a top-level window like so:

```
    SetParent(WindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
```